# Trigger on table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am interested to know about trigger execution in SQL Server.

I created an `INSERT` trigger for a table. And I insert 10 records from another table.

- How many times the trigger called? **One time or 10 times?**
- And how many records will be available in **INSERTED** table?

Comment: Have you even tried to find out yourself? Tested this at all?

Comment: No... I am going to use Trigger for the first time... I read some article and have this doubt...

Comment: I need to do something in quicker way... Instead of search and read article, I felt StackOverflow will make it in a quicker way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Triggers in SQL Server are called **once per statement** - so in your case:

- the trigger is called **ONCE** for your `INSERT` statement
- the pseudo table `Inserted` will contain all the **10 rows** that you're inserting

See [Data Points: Exploring SQL Server Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164047.aspx) on MSDN Magazine for a more in-depth look at triggers